# Atributos de Segurança

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Um amigo me perguntou uma forma de dar mais segurança na sua aplicação, para evitar um tipo de "injeção de url", ou seja, alguém digitar manualmente uma url "viciada" e burlar o sistema. Claro, existe vários tipos de criptografia que poderia ajudar, mas a injeção poderia burlar.

Uma vez vi um exemplo e acho que foi aqui no SOpt(não tenho certeza), alguém falando para criar um atributo de segurança que validasse sempre a classe que ele tem a necessidade de não permitir o "intruso". Pesquisei por "Atributo" e "Criar atributo" ou "Criação de Atributo" e não consegui encontrar nada, nem o que eu estava procurando e nada do gênero.

Então pergunto, como eu faço para criar um atributo que validasse sempre o usuário e senha, sem que esteja sempre pedindo isso do usuário, ou seja, à medida que o usuário adentrasse em determinados arquivos, o atributo já validasse esse usuário invisivelmente e se não tivesse direito de acesso, aí tratamos aqui?

Mas como criar o atributo em si, não vejo problemas, a questão é criar um atributo que validasse o usuário, isso não estou conseguindo fazer.

Comment: Estamos falando de ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Ele(meu colega) está usando webapi

Comment: A intenção que eu disse a ele, é criar um atributo e colocar em cima de cada classe que houver a necessidade de validação de usuário. Ao instanciar a classe, o objeto já valida o usuário.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tanto para ASP.NET MVC quanto para Web API, estamos falando do [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

[As perguntas que já respondi a respeito estão aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+authorize).

Basicamente é isto que ele faz: ao adentrar um *Controller* ou *Action* que tenha esse atributo marcado, o sistema faz uma validação do usuário, redirecionando a uma tela de Login se isto for necessário.

Comment: O que eu vi foi um atributo customizado, achei bem interessante, porem vou dar uma estudada no seu link e ver se é isso que estamos buscando. Então, o exemplo que o cara fez não redirecionava a tela de login, ele apenas validava o usuário já logado e se caso não fosse autorizado, ele dava uma mensagem ao usuário, mas isso nós customizamos aqui conforme a regra, mas o que não queremos é o redirecionamento para a tela de login, e não sei o porque disso, apenas é a regra para essa tarefa.

Comment: Nos links eu ensino como customizar o atributo de autorização.

Comment: Tô lendo e tentando ajudar o cara, usando o atributo em um webservice, é a mesma coisa? Tanto para asmx quanto para rest ou tem diferença grande?

Comment: Não. Pra WebService é melhor fazer uma pergunta mais específica.